# How do i multiple details view controls based on number of records i retrieved from the query in same page with delete button?

Tags: asp.net

How do i multiple details view controls based on number of records i retrieved from the query in same page with delete button?

My query may returns multiple records or one record. I could have bind the result in a grid view table but what i would like to do is iterate over the number of records and create details view in each tile dynamically. How do i dynamically created details view with delete button and bind the data?

How do i achieve this? I have never worked with asp.net web form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [repeater](http://nazimakul.com/article/repeater-itemcommand-event-in-asp-net_1049) and its [ItemDataBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.itemdatabound.aspx) and [ItemCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemcommand.aspx).

ItemDataBound is an event that fires once on your server for every record bound to the control. It is fired everytime a new item is binded to your data control.

ItemCommand is the event that will fire if you click a command button that is associated with the record. It is fired when the command event for a Button or LinkButton or ImageButton inside the data control is used.

Comment: Thank you, that solved my issue.  I need to add delete button that on click opens up modal pop as a confirmation with a field to insert reason for deletion which needs to be persist. How do i do it sir?

Comment: if the ID of that record is already exists in another table, Delete button should not be displayed. How do i do it aspx page? Is there a way to add all these in code behind so that i could easily check if and else for the button

Comment: You can do that with ItemDataBound. It will run for each row on code behind. You can customize there.

Answer (score 0):

use grid views rowdatabound event for iteration its explained in detail in here with example
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1e050f/rowdatabound-event-in-gridview-in-Asp-Net/
as for html in grid refer to